# shared_ptr to derived class from a specific base class

Tags: c++, oop, interface, derived-class

I feel like this is a pretty basic C++ question. I am trying to make a class which contains a member variable which is a shared_ptr to any class which is derived from a specific interface, but does not care which particular derived class it is. I am implementing it as follows:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  Base();
  virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};

class Derived : Base {
  Derived() {}
  void do_stuff() { };
};


class Foo
{

public:
  Foo() {
    mPtr = std::make_shared<Derived>();
  }

protected:
  std::shared_ptr<Base> mPtr;
};
```

Compiling gives the following error at the top:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::shared_ptr<Base>’ and ‘std::shared_ptr<Derived>’)
     mPtr = std::make_shared<Derived>();
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Edit: Changing inheritence from `Base` to `public Base` made it work. However, trying to instantiate the class makes the linker break.

```
Foo foo;
```

Compiling gives

```
libfoo.so: undefined reference to `Base::Base()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's this about?

Comment: Your inherit private, change it to ```class Derived : public Base```

Comment: You're inheriting privately from `Base`, it should be `class Derived : public Base {`. Also your `Derived` constructor and method are not public.

Comment: The default access specifier is `private` (for both bases and members) if you define a class with the `class` keyword. (And `public` if you define it with the `struct` keyword.)

Comment: Here is the fixed code compiling: [https://ideone.com/a6A2WD](https://ideone.com/a6A2WD)

Comment: Also, while not an issue in the code you are showing, you very likely want `Base` to have a virtual destructor. Without it trying to delete an object of derived type through a base class pointer will cause undefined behavior. `std::shared_ptr` behaves in a way that this is not an issue (it will not delete through a base class pointer), but the same code with e.g. `std::unique_ptr` instead will have undefined behavior for that reason.

Comment: Unrelated, but please make it a habit to use the `override` special identifier for functions you override. As in `void do_stuff() override { }` in your `Derived` class. That will make the compiler be able to detect and give errors if you mistakenly use the wrong signature or return type in the child class.

Comment: @user17732522 will `std::shared_ptr` properly destroy object after converted to `std::shared<Base>` ?

Comment: @Slava yes - thats the point of the extra magic done by `shared_ptr` is that it does work this way.

Comment: @Slava Yes, I think the expression used to destroy the object is always supposed to be determined from initial construction of the ownership group and stored in the control block. For `std::make_shared`, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/util.smartptr.shared#create-7.11 which uses the actually initialized type and similarly for construction via the `std::shared_ptr` constructor without deleter argument, https://eel.is/c++draft/util.sharedptr#util.smartptr.shared.dest-1.3 refers to the "owned pointer" which is the collectively owned pointer, not specific to the instance.

Comment: @user17732522 I see, good to know, though I do not think it justifies omitting vritual dtor.

Comment: @Slava Yes, agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the access specifiers and more:

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;            // must have implementation

    // virtual dtor - not strictly needed for shared_ptr:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {    // public inheritance
public:                          // public access
    // Derived() {}              // not needed
    void do_stuff() override {}; // mark override 
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() :
        mPtr{std::make_shared<Derived>()} // use the member init-list
    {}

private:                         // prefer private member variables
    std::shared_ptr<Base> mPtr;
};
```

Comment: Actully if it is strictly needed is a good question. Does `std::shared_ptr` provide that guarantee?

Comment: @Slava The `shared_ptr` stores this information in its control block so it will "do the right thing" - but if someone uses `Base* foo = new Derived;` - it's going to break at `delete foo;` (without the `virtual` dtor).

Comment: I got the answer, yes it is seems to be guaranteed, but that guarantee should not be used. There are many ways it can be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Derived should use public inheritance, rather than private inheritance, and `Derived()` should be public.

```
class Derived : public Base 
{
public:
   Derived() {}
   void do_stuff() override{ };
};
```